# How do I delete files with a pattern?

Tags: bash, file, delete-file

I have some files whose name is postfixed by (copy), which I want to remove. For example: f1.jpg, f1(copy).jpg, f2.jpg, f2(copy).jpg. What command can I Use to remove all copy files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `rm` command to remove files:

```
rm *\(copy\)*
```

The `\`s are needed because parentheses are special to the shell. Alternatively, `rm *copy*`.

Answer (score 2):

Or `find` with its wonderful (non-POSIX) `-delete` switch:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*(copy).jpg' -type f -delete
```

This can be superior to globs in case you have *a lot* of files, where globs would yield a *Argument list too long* error. It might be faster too in case of lots of files. The `-maxdepth 1` switch (not POSIX) to avoid recursion into subdirectories. The `-type f` switch to only deal with files. You can add the `-print` switch if you want to see which files are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

please try this if you  `rm -rf "*\(copy\)*.jpg"`

Comment: With quoting you suppress globbing.